# React-Native: How to get Screen Lock time?

Tags: react-native

I need to find whether the application sent in background manually or automatically? In react-native, if the screen gets locked, the app state treats it as background. It doesn't matters if you intentionally send the app to background(by either killing the app or pressing home button) or it was sent in the background automatically(due to screen lock). Is it possible to distinguish both events? Is there any way in react-native to find out the device's screen lock time?

After a long search I found this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-home-pressed